# Transactions slow after Spring 3 / Hibernate 6 update

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having performance issues in integration tests where a primary for-loop is called around 1000 times after upgrading to the latest Spring/Hibernate versions.

[image]

The tested function uses a distributed locker (via etcd) to lock the db and it has the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` annotation, see the screenshots. The function called in the second for loop has the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {…})` annotation. Setting the propagation strategies to default does not improve the performance. I am kind of lost here, where do all the additional transaction commits come from after the upgrade, why was the handling different before? Is this my own misconfiguration or an issue of Hibernate or Spring?

Comment: It isn't clear in your question what you are really showing. We have no idea what the code is or does, or what exactly you are describing is happening differently. If you think this is a transaction handling issue - maybe remove all other changes in the version upgrades: test with only the Spring libraries being changed, using Hibernate 6.2.6 in both (or 5.6.15 in both), and then file a regression bug with Spring to get help.